# The error I get is 'Msg 8120,'Vendors.VendorName' is invalid in the select list'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, max

```
select 
    VendorID, 
    VendorName, 
    VendorCity, 
    VendorState, 
    VendorPhone, 
    concat(VendorContactFName, ' ',VendorContactFName) AS VendorContactFullName, 
    max(InvoiceDueDate)
from 
    Vendors v 
inner join 
    InvoiceArchive IVA on v.VendorID = IVA.VendorID
where 
    VendorCity in ('California', 'Arizona', 'Nevada');
```

Comment: California, Arizona and Nevada aren't exactly **cities** ..... shouldn't that be `where VendorState in (.....) ` ??

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for an aggregete query. This implies that you need to list all non-aggregated columns in a `group by` clause. That would look like:

```
select 
    v.VendorID, 
    v.VendorName, 
    v.VendorCity, 
    v.VendorState, 
    v.VendorPhone, 
    concat(v.VendorContactFName, ' ', v.VendorContactFName) AS VendorContactFullName, 
    max(iv.InvoiceDueDate) 
from Vendors v 
inner join InvoiceArchive IVA on v.VendorID = IVA.VendorID 
where v.VendorCity in ('California','Arizona','Nevada')
group by 
    v.VendorID, 
    v.VendorName, 
    v.VendorCity, 
    v.VendorState, 
    v.VendorPhone,
    v.VendorContactFName, 
    v.VendorContactFName
```

Note that in this query, all column names are *qualified* with the table they belong to.

You can get the same results with `cross apply`, which does not require aggregation:

```
select 
    v.VendorID, 
    v.VendorName, 
    v.VendorCity, 
    v.VendorState, 
    v.VendorPhone, 
    concat(v.VendorContactFName, ' ', v.VendorContactFName) AS VendorContactFullName, 
    iv.MaxInvoiceDueDate
from Vendors v
cross apply (
    select max(iva.InvoiceDueDate) MaxInvoiceDueDate
    from InvoiceArchive iva 
    where iva.VendorID = v.VendorID 
) iva
```